# Xwayland crashes frequently

Tags: ubuntu, login, wayland, plymouth

My system is running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I am facing this bug every time I turn on my pc and when my PC wakes up after sleep. Unfortunately, I found no solution when I searched on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1758651) and Bugzilla.

I have also reported this error every time(1000+ times now) I get it, no fixes yet. In spite of the Xwayland crash, I can successfully login via GDM3 and use Gnome desktop without any problem, but I am not able to resume my work when my PC wakes from sleep (this hurts).

Error details:

```
Executable path: /usr/bin/Xwayland
Package: xwayland 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4
Problem Type: Crash
Title: Xwayland crashed with signal 7 in mieqProcessDeviceEvent()
ApportVersion: 2.20.9-0ubuntu72
Architecture: amd64
Machine Type: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. GL552JX.
```

For Bootlog, CurrentDmesg: I will share it when requested via a drive link because it is huge to be posted as text.

---

Update: The error occurs only when my system is using Intel integrated graphics(Intel Iris Pro 5200). So, temporarily to avoid the error, I have switched to Nvidia Graphics(Nvidia GTX 950M, Driver version: 390.87), no errors since then. But, Dedicated GPU rapidly consumes my laptop battery, I would prefer to use Intel Graphics if the error gets solved.

Comment: I am asking this question on StackExchange because I am hoping for an answer due to its large number of users compared to actual bug report sites, For more details please ask it in comments I will share the logs via drive link.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. It does not happen at every wake, though, only like 30% of the time.

Comment: What GPU manufacture do you have?

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev It's Intel Iris Pro 5200 + Dedicated Nvidia GTX 950M. This Wayland error appears when I switch to Intel Graphics. I do not get any error while my system is using Nvidia GPU.

Comment: @FutureJJ ..and you don't use Nvidia proprietary driver, correct?

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev I am using Nvidia proprietary driver version: 390.87, actually as mentioned before, I am not getting this error when I switch to Nvidia Graphics, this error only occurs when I am using Intel Integrated Graphics via Nvidia X Server Settings.

Comment: @FutureJJ Thank you for the information provided. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a root/admin user use vi/vim editor to perform the following changes of the GDM3 custom configuration file

> /etc/gdm3/custom.conf

From:

```
 #WaylandEnable=false
```

To:

```
 WaylandEnable=false
```

By uncommenting the above line your system will use the Xorg display manager instead of Wayland next time it boots. Just do a reboot and you are done :).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and post the results in the comments.

Comment: Worked perfectly for my (possibly unrelated) Wayland on Gnome 3 problem: Ubuntu not booting properly, always have to cycle power once.